# How can I load strictly tiles within the current viewport in Leaflet.js?

Tags: leaflet, tiles, mapbox, ajax

I have tiles that are not available for the whole map.  How can I stop Leaflet.js/Mapbox.js from making requests to these tiles?  There are dozens of HTTP 404's that I'd really like to get rid of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[tileBounds](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/991)

Try researching that link.

Also: [Tile Layer Bounding Box Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18446110/leafletjs-load-tile-layer-based-on-bounding-box)

Or modify [errorTileUrl](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-errortileurl) to help your cause. Perhaps try `errorTileUrl: ""`

Comment: thanks, i'll look into tileBounds especially. Won't errorTileUrl only fire after a 404 though? I'd like to limit the XMLHttpRequests as much as posssible - I'm generating hundreds of 404's...

Comment: I added a third link: the Tile Layer Bounding Box Example link. That guy lays out the code for you.

Comment: Yeah, looks great. Do you know if it's possible to embed this information in the Layer itself? (That it's self-aware of its bounds?)

Comment: Subdomains help increase the number of simultaneous HTTP requests, but I do not know more than that to say whether it is a problem worth taking time up over.

Comment: Also, not sure about embedding the bounds info into the layer. Perhaps the best thing you can do (hacky) is a listen event to remove the layer, and then re-add with updated bounds. I don't think there is a way to .setOptions on the tileLayer

Comment: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-moveend

Comment: Also, is it possible to request the bounds from the layer service? If you could get that info at the beginning, you could set it once and be done. Please accept the answer if this works for ya. - B

Comment: I'm not quite there yet. Really appreciate your help! Do you know if there is a callback for 404'd tiles?  Ie. a real callback, not just an alt url?